# Postgresql update query (with a subquery) error

Tags: postgresql

I am getting error on this query. The first inner query is executing properly while we run it independently. But while I include the same in the complete query, its prompting the error.

```
UPDATE GL_BudgetPlanDetails bpd 
SET (CommittedAmt07) = (
        SELECT SUM (case
            when fa.amtacctdr > 0 then (fa.amtacctdr*-1)
            when fa.amtacctcr > 0 then fa.amtacctcr else 0 end )
        FROM fact_acct fa
        WHERE fa.datetrx between '2014-09-01' and '2014-09-30'
          AND fa.isactive ='Y'
          AND fa.account_ID =758
          AND fa.AD_Client_ID =11
          AND fa.AD_Org_ID =50001)
WHERE (
        (
            SELECT gbp.c_year_id
              FROM GL_BudgetPlan gbp
             WHERE gbp.GL_BudgetPlan_ID = bpd.GL_BudgetPlan_ID
               AND gbp.isactive ='Y'
        ) = '2014'
      )
AND bpd.account_ID =758
```

Comment: And the error is? (and please format the statement so that it's visible without horizontal scrolling)

Comment: "*its prompting the error.*" That's like saying "it doesn't work". Show the **exact text** of the error message by *editing your question* to add it (do NOT paste it in a comment). Then comment here when you've made your edits. While you're at it, please include your PostgreSQL version.

Answer (score 2):

Remove brackets of CommittedAmt07

UPDATE GL_BudgetPlanDetails bpd SET Period01Amt=(SELECT SUM (case when fa.amtacctdr > 0 then (fa.amtacctdr*-1) when fa.amtacctcr > 0 
then fa.amtacctcr else 0 end ) FROM fact_acct fa WHERE fa.datetrx between '2014-09-01' and '2014-09-30' AND fa.isactive ='Y'  AND fa.account_ID =758 
AND fa.AD_Client_ID =11 AND fa.AD_Org_ID =50001) WHERE ((SELECT gbp.c_year_id 
FROM GL_BudgetPlan gbp WHERE gbp.GL_BudgetPlan_ID = bpd.GL_BudgetPlan_ID AND gbp.isactive ='Y' ) = '2014') AND bpd.account_ID =758

Comment: That might be correct, but it's kind of illegible and doesn't *explain* why it's correct. An edit might be warranted.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue are the () arround `CommittedAmt07` so your query should look like

```
UPDATE GL_BudgetPlanDetails bpd 
SET CommittedAmt07 = (
        SELECT SUM (case
            when fa.amtacctdr > 0 then (fa.amtacctdr*-1)
            when fa.amtacctcr > 0 then fa.amtacctcr else 0 end )
        FROM fact_acct fa
        WHERE fa.datetrx between '2014-09-01' and '2014-09-30'
          AND fa.isactive ='Y'
          AND fa.account_ID =758
          AND fa.AD_Client_ID =11
          AND fa.AD_Org_ID =50001)
WHERE (
        (
            SELECT gbp.c_year_id
              FROM GL_BudgetPlan gbp
             WHERE gbp.GL_BudgetPlan_ID = bpd.GL_BudgetPlan_ID
               AND gbp.isactive ='Y'
        ) = '2014'
      )
AND bpd.account_ID =758;
```

If you are having a look onto [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-update.html), you can see that there doesn't need to be brackets if you just update one column. But you will need to use them ones you update it with some kind of a array. See this example from documentation

```
UPDATE weather SET (temp_lo, temp_hi, prcp) = (temp_lo+1, temp_lo+15, DEFAULT)
WHERE city = 'San Francisco' AND date = '2003-07-03';
```

Also for 9.3 they are stating that filling it from a SELECT-statement is not yet implmeented (on the very low of the linked page)